# How to get Geoserver to use the MongoDB-Geo-Index for Heatmap Transformations?

Tags: mongodb, geoserver, geotools

We are currently trying to switch the backend for our Geoserver from Postgis to MongoDB.
Apart from our Geoserver-Heatmap Transformations it is working quite well.

While visualizing the Heatmap Geoserver seems to ignore the BBox constrains, this results in a full table scan even when zooming in.
Normally a filtering with `$geoIntersec` is done on the defined BBox, but not while using 
the Heatmap Transformation.
Anybody with similar problem and possibly a solution?

We are using Geoserver Version 2.15.2.
Here the Geoserver logs with the logged MongoDB query.

```
2020-04-12 20:46:27,226 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2020-04-12 20:46:27,227 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2020-04-12 20:46:27,227 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2020-04-12 20:46:27,227 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2020-04-12 20:46:27,227 INFO [org.geoserver.flow] - Control-flow inactive, there are no configured rules
2020-04-12 20:46:27,229 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.HeatmapProcess
2020-04-12 20:46:27,230 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class java.lang.Integer
2020-04-12 20:46:27,232 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite] - Computed scale denominator: 1063.361240291149
2020-04-12 20:46:27,233 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2020-04-12 20:46:27,233 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite] - creating rules for scale denominator - 1,063.361
2020-04-12 20:46:27,233 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite] - Processing 1 stylers for test:stations2
2020-04-12 20:46:27,233 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite] - Expanding rendering area by 1 pixels to consider stroke width
2020-04-12 20:46:27,233 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite] - Querying layer test:stations2 with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[16.83694749302019 : 16.83789164596449, 47.864875483641775 : 47.86694080816731]
2020-04-12 20:46:27,234 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.HeatmapProcess
2020-04-12 20:46:27,234 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class java.lang.Integer
2020-04-12 20:46:27,235 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.mongodb] - find({ }, { "geometry" : 1 , "contact.mail" : 1 , "name" : 1 , "count" : 1 , "measurements.unit" : 1 , "measurements.values.time" : 1 , "_id" : 1 , "id" : 1 , "measurements.name" : 1 , "measurements.values.value" : 1})
```